# Let $p:X \to Y$ be a closed continuous map. If for each $y \in Y, p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact in $X$ and if $X$ is Hausdorff so is $Y$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $p:X \to Y$ be a surjective closed continuous map. If for each $y \in Y, p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact in $X$ and if $X$ is Hausdorff so is $Y$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $y_1,y_2 \in Y$ be distinct. Then their preimages are disjoint. That is,

$$p^{-1}(\{y_1\}) \cap p^{-1}(\{y_2\})=\varnothing.$$

As the $p^{-1}(\{y_j\})$ for $j=1,2$ are compact subspaces of a Hausdorff space they're both closed. And I know disjoint compact closed sets of Hausdorff space can be separated via disjoint open sets so there exists (disjoint) open sets $U,V \subset X$ such that

$$p^{-1}(\{y_1\}) \subset U, p^{-1}(\{y_2\}) \subset V.$$

Then $y_1 \in p(U)$ and $y_2 \in p(V)$ but I cannot guarantee the openness of $p(U),p(V)$ in $Y$. What am I missing?? Could I say that $p(X \setminus U)$ is closed as $U$ is open. Somehow use this to conclude $p(U) \subset Y$ is open?

Comment: Two deleted answers, unfortunately. The surjectivity is an essential assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take 2.

Fix distinct $y_1,y_2\in Y$ and write $X_1=p^{-1}(y_1),X_2=p^{-1}(y_2)$. These are compact.

As $X$ is Hausdorff, you are right that there is an open $U\supseteq X_1$ and an open $V\supseteq X_2$ with $U\cap V=\emptyset$. Let $K_1:=X\setminus U$ and $K_2:=X\setminus V$. These are both closed, though possibly non-disjoint.

$K_1\cup K_2=X\setminus(U\cap V)=X$, so $p(K_1),p(K_2)$ form a closed cover of $Y$. But then $Y\setminus p(K_1)\supseteq p(X_1)=\{y_1\}$ and $Y\setminus p(K_2)\supseteq p(X_2)=\{y_2\}$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods, as desired.

Comment: Ahhh I knew I had to do something with the complements .. thanks!!

Comment: No worries. ${}{}{}$